# Get the HTTPURLResponse from a Siesta Response

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I'm fighting against REST API that performs a 304 redirect; what I need is to take the destination URL of the redirect and open it with the browser (I know, it's a little of a perversion). I successfully intercepted the redirect, thanks to this nice lad reversepanda:
https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/issues/210
but still I didn't figure out how to take the redirect url in the   callback of the GET request (success or failure)

```
resource.load().onSuccess{ response in
        //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO TAKE THE URL OF THE REDIRECT 
        //(if I print the response I can see the HTML of the destination web page where the user should land)
    }.onFailure{ error in
        //using 'completionHandler(nil)' in the 'willPerformHTTPRedirection' method of the delegate, brings me here
    }
```

Any suggestion on how I could resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) 304 redirect?? Do you mean 301 or 302?(2) Does the Location header not appear in the response entity?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 307 (it was a typo). How can I retrieve the location from the header? If I print all the response.headers, I don't see a "location"

Comment: Siesta’s `Entity` type has a [`headers`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Structs/Entity.html#/s:6Siesta6EntityV7headerss10DictionaryVyS2SGv) property.

Comment: correct, that's what I'm talking about when I say that I'm printing "response.headers". But in the headers I can't see the location

Answer (score 0):

Take a look inside RequestChain.swift, it has some comments with example which can help. I believe you can do something like:

```
func redirectRequest() -> Request {
  return self.yourAnotherRequest(onSuccess: {
    }, onFailure: { error in
  })
}

func yourRequest(request: Siesta.Request) -> Request {
  return request.chained {
    guard case .failure(let error) = $0.response,
        error.httpStatusCode == 401 else {
            return .useThisResponse
    }

    return .passTo(
        self.redirectRequest().chained {
            if case .failure = $0.response {
                return .useThisResponse
            } else {
                return .passTo(request.repeated())
            }
        }
    )
  }
}
```

You can search more examples with keywords `chained`, `useThisResponse` and `passTo` in Siesta sources.

Please, let us know if it helps to solve your issue and it would be nice to see your final solution.